# Create subdirectory in Finder tree view

Tags: finder

Currently, I am only able to create a subdirectory in `Finder` by double-clicking the parent dir so that it becomes the top level selected in the main panel and creating it there by right-clicking and then selecting `New Folder`.  However, I like to always view my directory structure from a very high level in the hierarchy, most often my home directory and would like to be able to create a subdirectory of a subdirectory without being in it, i.e. from the tree view.  When I right click it, I do not get an option to create a new folder, like I do when I actually have it selected in the main panel.  Is there any way to enable this feature without installing any plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge, but ⇧⌘N creates a new folder in the same manner.